# php asterisk ami получить статус звонка

Tags: php, callback, asterisk

я новичок в этом деле, поэтому не сочтите за глупость такой вопрос, как получить статус звонка. Суть в следующем, по нажатию на кнопке я совершаю вызов абоненту. В результате я должен получить статус этого вызова:
к примеру вернуть:
1 если абонент не взял трубку
2 если абонент занят
3 если абонент недоступен
4 если абонент взял трубку
5 если звонок завершен

звонок у меня получается, делаю я это следующим образом:

```html
$strhost = "111.111.111.111"; //ip адрес астериска
$strport = "111"; // порт
$errno = 0;
$errstr = 0;
$actionID = time();
  
$sconn = @fsockopen($strhost, $strport, $errno, $errstr) or die('0');
if (!$sconn) {
 echo '0'; // нужен для того чтобы вывести сообщение на js что звонок не состоялся
 exit; 
} else {
 $username = 'username'; // имя пользователя
 $secret = 'secret'; // пароль
 $timeout = 60000; // ожидание установки соединения
 $channel = 'SIP/111'; // канал который будет принимать звонки
 $callerid = '8911*******'; // уникальное имя звонка, то что будет видно на телефоне
 $exten = '89111111111'; // номер клиента на который будем звонить
 $context = 'from-internal'; // используемый контекст вызова
 $priority = 1;

 fputs($sconn, "Action: login\r\n");
 fputs($sconn, "Username: $username\r\n");
 fputs($sconn, "Secret: $secret\r\n");
 fputs($sconn, "Events: off\r\n\r\n");  
 fputs($sconn, "Action: Originate\r\n");
 fputs($sconn, "Channel: $channel\r\n");
 fputs($sconn, "Timeout: $timeout\r\n");
 fputs($sconn, "Callerid: $callerid\r\n");
 fputs($sconn, "Exten: $exten\r\n");
 fputs($sconn, "Context: $context\r\n");
 fputs($sconn, "Priority: $priority\r\n");
 fputs($sconn, "ActionID: $actionID\r\n");
 fputs($sconn, "Async: yes\r\n\r\n" );
 fputs($sconn, "Action: Logoff\r\n\r\n");
 fclose($sconn);
 
 echo '1'; // нужен для того чтобы вывести сообщение на js что звонок состоялся
 exit; 
}
```

Каким образом, мне получить статус звонка с этим $actionID и в какой момент это надо делать.
У меня логика такая, что после того как я нажал на кнопку вызов, и мне вернуло echo '1';
я должен запускать каждые скажем 10 секунд функцию, которая будет проверять статус этого звонка, до тех пор пока мне не вернется что вызов завершен.
Но как получить этот статус?

я думал что это можно сделать следующим образом, код который будет запускаться для получения статуса (часть кода):

```html
fputs($sconn, "Action: Login\r\n");
fputs($sconn, "Username: $username\r\n");
fputs($sconn, "Secret: $secret\r\n");
fwrite($sconn, "Action: Status\r\n");
fputs($sconn, "Action: Logoff\r\n\r\n");

$wrets = '';
while (!feof($sconn)) {
 $wrets .= fread($sconn, 8192).'\r\n';
}
```

и в переменной $wrets я уже выдерну статус и верну его, но к сожалению у меня ничего не выходит, либо я делаю обсалютно неправильно.